# Saving a Localizable.strings

Tags: iphone, localization, localizable.strings

As I am developing my project I want to prepare for localisation and add all my strings into string Macro NSLocalizedString calls and then use the Localizable.string to give values to these keys.

I created a string file from within my xCode project and saved the file in my en.lproj folder. However when I came to use it the key values that were entered in the Localizable.strings did not get registered in my code and so the strings that were displaying were the keys that I had entered in the macros. However if I save the Localizable.strings file not in the en.lproj folder, everything works as expected. This seems odd to me as I was expecting that all items for localisation need to be stored in .lproj folders.

Could anybody let me know what is the correct way of doing this, and will I have issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't working when in en.lproj might be character encoding?

check out:

http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

"If strings in your Localizable.strings file are present in the translated file, but aren’t being localized on the iPhone, check the character encoding of the file.

Unlike the iPhone simulator, the iPhone only recognizes strings files that are formatted UTF-16. Always test your localizations on the device, as the simulator and the device do not always behave the same way."

Answer (score 0):

"so the strings that were displaying were the keys that I had entered in the macros. "

Do you have them backwards?  Try swapping one of the keys and words in the localizable.strings file and see if that is the problem.